# Homebrew installation failing on MacOS BigSur

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xcode, macos, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I am trying to install Homebrew but it's failing to install. Here are the errors that I am getting:

```
error: unable to unlink old 'Library/Homebrew/brew.sh': Operation not permitted
fatal: Could not reset index file to revision 'origin/master'.
Failed during: git reset --hard origin/master
```

When running using sudo I get the below error:

```
Don't run this as root!
```

Comment: Could you navigate to `Library/Homebrew/brew.sh`, temporarily delete `brew.sh` and try again?

Comment: @JacobJohn Looks like there's no folder called as Homebrew or a file called as brew.sh

Answer (score 0):

Update:
Looks like this might have been some bug in Big sur. There was no folder called as Homebrew or a file called as brew.sh when navigating using terminal or go to. Due to this it was giving this error. But when searched from the finder, the folder was somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

Please try this